# non-unique limit points

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space (not metric space) and let $x_1,x_2,...,x_n,...$ is a sequence of points in $X$. We say that $x_n \rightarrow x$ if for each open set $U \ni x$ for all $n \ge n_0$. Find an expample of a topological space and a sequence such that $x_n \rightarrow x$ and $x_n \rightarrow y$ but $x \ne y$.

My answer was $\tau = \{\emptyset, X\}$

Would that be a correct answer to this question?

Comment: Your definition of $x_n \to x$ is missing something.  It should say, "for each open set $U \ni x$ there exists $n_0$ such that $x_n \in U$ for all $n \ge n_0$."

Comment: @HenryW.   Not quite any non-Hausdorff topology.  It's possible that $x$ and $y$ have no disjoint neighbourhoods but there is no **sequence** $x_n$ that converges to, but is never equal to, $x$.  A non-Hausdorff first-countable space would do.

Comment: The question asks you to provide both a space **and** a sequence in that space that converges to two different points of the space. Since you’ve not provided a sequence, let alone demonstrated that it converges to two different points, you clearly have not answered the question. If $|X|\ge 2$, the indiscrete topology on $X$ will indeed work but you still have to finish your answer. What sequence do you want to use, and to what two distinct points of $X$ does it converge?